# How to "jump" a single transform value in an animation?

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transforms

I'm trying to make a transform function value "jump" in an animation.

My `@keyframes` rule has 3 percetanges with transform property in each one. I want the **only** scale to go from 0.5 to 1 from the **first** to the **third** percentagens (same that happens with the color change) instead of going from first to second.

I know it happens because the transform applies a `scale(1)` implicitly in the second percentage.

Is it possible to do this without having to create more than one animation?

```css
.block {
  background-color: #333;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 100px;
  animation: rolling 3s forwards infinite;
}
@keyframes rolling {
  33% {
    background: green;
    transform: scale(0.5);
  } 66% {
    transform: translate(20%);
  } 100% {
    background: red;
    transform: scale(1) translate(100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a `scale` value manually

```css
.block {
  background-color: #333;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 100px;
  animation: rolling 3s forwards infinite;
}

@keyframes rolling {
  33% {
    background: green;
    transform: scale(0.5);
  } 66% {
    transform: scale(0.75) translate(50%);
  } 100% {
    background: red;
    transform: scale(1) translate(100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I don't want to lose the other properties of transform in the second percentage. In that case, translateX of 50%, but it could be 20%, 80%, etc.

Comment: You will need to set `scale` implicitly as an in-between value in that case. Check edit

Comment: Sorry, not what I'm looking for. I want the scale to happen from first to third. Not first, then second, then third. Only scale, the othe tranform values can happen in each stage normally. I'm not sure if it is possible, but I was trying to solve this for a while.

Comment: No worries..it probably isn't possible